# How to update a django moodel value from a button click in a class based view

Tags: python, django, templates, model

i currently have a model that looks like:

**Model**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_best_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def set_best_answer(self):
        self.is_best_answer = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('question-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.question.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Answer by {self.author} with text: {self.content}"
```

I have a Class based Listview which lists all of the answers above. I want to add a button in the template that would update the value in the model of is_best_answer to True e.g.

**html**

`<a class="btn btn-outline-dark " href="{% url 'select' answer.id %}">Set Best Answer</a>`

**view**

```
def set_best_(request, pk):
    answer = Answer.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    answer.set_best_answer()

    return redirect('/')
```

**url**

```
path('answer/<int:pk>/best-answer/',  set_best, name='select'),
```

The above works for me, but i have had to call a function rather than anything to do with the class based views. Is there a better way?

Dango version 3.1

Comment: my comment is not trying to answer your question. To me, using ajax will be better for user experience in this case. You have a list of answers, the user can check the best answer, you send it via ajax and change is_best_answer to True in the backend. The best thing is that the user does not need to leave the page.

Comment: I will be using Ajax in the future for this but just wondered on general best practice in the model view template world.